# Use JMeter HTTP Proxy to record HTTP request from not-a-browser client

Tags: jmeter

I have a client/server configuration.

In the client I have an application that talks to the server by http/https withou a browser being used.

I want to know how to configure client and jmeter to record the http requests being send from client to server

The client is a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several options:

1. Your application has dedicated proxy configuration. In this case just configure it to use JMeter as a proxy
2. Your application respects [OS-level proxy settings](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-10-build-9879-proxy-server-settings/d7bbc6dd-5539-4e68-93c1-9401468701b5?auth=1). For Windows 10 hit "Win + S" and type "proxy". Perform proxy configuration at all available locations:

   [image: Windows 10 configure proxy]

If everything goes well you should be able to record your application network activity using JMeter. Refer to [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) for a little bit more detailed information and some troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Ok. But now, what address and port should i put in the OS manual proxy settings? if jmeter is in the same machine can i put local? what about the port? what port should I use. Thanks.

Comment: If you use default JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder settings (i.e. using [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)) use `localhost`or `127.0.0.1` as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port. Be aware that you may have to install [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc708322(v=ws.10).aspx) in order to be able to capture local traffic.